# Google Apps Calendar API Push Event Query

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-apps, server-push, asp.net-web-api

Had a good hunt around for an answer to this google apps query but can't find a direct answer so going to flick this one out to the community.

The plan: We have a Google Apps domain account and we want to make use of the calendar API and create a PHP web app that pushes events to the calendars of all users of a google apps domain when triggered.

Question: Is it possible to push to all users?  Or from what I read is this impossible to achieve this without the users actually being logged in etc and authorizing itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont believe this is possible, wanted to try and set up a 'push to all' feature a while back, but no luck.

The best consolation is maybe creating one shared user/calendar  and then sharing that out across all of the accounts.  So a new user, with calendar title 'ExampleEventsForGroup' would then be shared back to Tom, Dick & Mary, and they could also add/modify events onto that calendar, thus pushing back out to all members.

Its a workaround, but for us, it works!

Rick